# Hover navigation menu with non-nested elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a hover menu effect using JQuery. The perfect example of what I am looking for can be found at http://www.godaddy.com/ (check out the green bar)

All the example I have seen are using UL and LI with nested elements. However, I am looking to achieve this with elements that are not nested. If you check the source for godaddy then you can see these elements are non-nested just like I want.

Imagine I have some mark-up as follows...

```
<div>
   <a id="button1"><img .../></a>
   <a id="button2"><img .../></a>
   <a id="button3"><img .../></a>
</div>
<div id="menu1">
   //anything I want in here (links, labels etc.)
</div>
```

I would like to be able to create a javascript function that can be called to setup these menus as follows...

```
SetupMenu("#button1", "#menu1");
```

this function will position the div element (which is absolute) and this I can do without issue. The bit I cannot work out is for the hover events. I have a simple example of these events...

```
$(button).mouseenter(function (e) {
   $(menu).show();
});
$(button).mouseleave(function (e) {
   $(menu).hide();
});
```

Obviously this works great for showing the menu, but when you want to mouse over the menu, then the mouse leave is fired for the button (as I would expect). I know this is the wrong approach but am just showing where I am at the moment.

Thanks for any help

Related CSS is as follows (modified names for example purposes)...

```
#menu1
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    min-width:100px;
    padding:10px 10px 20px 10px;
}

#button1
{
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: @Ahsan - Added CSS form menu and button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var intVal = 0;
$(button).mouseenter(function (e) {
   $(menu).show();
});
$(button).mouseleave(function (e) {
  intVal=  setTimeout(function() { $(menu).hide(); }, 1000);
});

$(menu).mouseenter(function() {
   clearTimeout(intVal);
});
$(menu).mouseleave(function(e) {
   $(this).hide();
}
```

This can help you, your menu wont be hidden until 1 second, but if mouse is over your opened menu it will clear timeout and menu will be opened till mouseleave.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the clearTimeout does not seem to work - the function is called but it has no effect and the $(menu).hide() still gets processed (I assume the intVal is not being matched). I tried moving intVAl to global but no good. Also, I believe this may cause issue with more than one menu?

Comment: do not add intVal into $(document).ready or any other method, put it in root so it can be global variable, so call it

Comment: Yes I have added it as global variable (which I did before) and now it is working (maybe a cache thing before). I was worried that the global val would cause conflict with multiple menus but it seems to work fine. I will do some additional testing but if all goes well I will accept this answer shortly

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out your code. But I think you have to use `ul` & `li` combinations for your dropdown menues.

See a simple example by clicking [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/e96pc/)

Comment: What is not to figure out? Anyway, I have my answer. And I specifically said I do not want to use UL and LI as that requires having the button and menu items nested

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me. First I wrapped both the buttons and menu in an element and then with JavaScript I hide the menu on mouse out of the wrapper element. Second I use JavaScript to loop through all of the menus and hide them on mouse out of any button. Lastly I show the associated menu on mouse over of the button.

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!--On mouse OUT hide all menus -->

  <div>
    <a id="button1"></a> <!--On mouse OVER hide all menus then show associated menu -->
    <a id="button2"></a>
    <a id="button3"></a>
  </div>

  <div id="menu1">
    anything I want in here (links, labels etc.)
  </div>

</div>
```